# What can I use as an Action Bar replacement in Monodroid?

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin.android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to port a Monotouch app to Monodroid. My app has to target Android 2.1 as a minimum, but the Action Bar only seems to be available for Android 3.0 and upwards.

The iOS app is making use of the title bar all the time, so I'm looking for some action bar replacement that can be re-used from action to action.

What are my options for solving this problem? I know there are native android libraries tackling this problem (i.e. https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar), but communicating with them through JNI looks quite error-prone and tedious. Is there any better solution?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please look at my implementation of ActionBar here https://github.com/soundnRg/ActionBar. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks grea! Just one thing though: It only compiles if I delete the Dispose() method in ActionBar.cs, and this probably creates a memory leak I suppose that simply deleting Dispose creates a memory leak. See the following screenshot: screencast.com/t/kMVhtjXKZOJ . Please help! :)

Comment: You can use "new" keyword to override Dispose() method of Object class and invoke base.Dispose() method;

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that, but since there was this compilation error I was under the impression that something else is possibly wrong. Anyway, thanks for solving my problem!

Comment: In Mono for Android 4.0, you should override the `Dispose(bool)` method, not the `Dispose()` method. See the Breaking Changes section in the 4.0 release notes: http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_4/Release_4.0.0#Breaking_Changes

Comment: have updated the code due to new Dispose pattern in MonoDroid 4, enjoy.